# using jQuery to retrieve all Product data using JSON

Tags: jquery, json, product, bigcommerce

i need to display Product Description and other info on my homepage; but BigCommerce global %%GLOBAL_ProductDescription%% only displays on the product detail page

i'm trying to use this to get the product info, but am having trouble with the authentication; i can do it successfully via curl, but not with javascript

Thanks for your help... here is my code:

```
    var product_id = '92662';

    // run this code to get all the info on this product
    var my_url = "https://store-XXXXX.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/" + product_id;

    var my_json = $.getJSON( my_url, { username: "my_user_name", api_key: "xxx_my_api_key_here_xxx" } )
    .done(function( json ) {
    console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.product.description );


    });
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!